# Autodesk Graphic: saving vector file to 200x300 pixels

Tags: vector, export, raster

I have a vector image that I'm trying to export for an area of a web page that's 200x300 pixels. When I export it, the quality of the image is significantly reduced. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Hi Emily, welcome to GD.SE! Can you explain how and what setting you used to save the vector file for web?

Comment: And what software you're using!

Comment: I'm currently using Autodesk Graphic.

Comment: I have the canvas size set to 300x200 with 72 ppi. But for whatever reason, unless I export as a PDF (which I'm trying to avoid), the text looses its crispness. Is there a way to export it without blurring the lines of the text?

Comment: How much text? A full page? How many pixels high is each character now?

Comment: You can't have much text on a 200x300 file!

Answer (score 0):

Of course you loose "crispness" in fact you limit a lot the information you can have on an image so tiny.

You do not "loose" crispness in a pdf file because pdf is still a vector file, so if you zoom in you still have full detail on text.

You can not avoid that. But there is a little bit you can do to improve it.

Try exporting at double size 400x600 and resampling the image using gimp. After resampling apply some sharpness.

But perhaphs you simply have too much text on the tiny image. Try to optimize that. **If it is a banner for example optimize your information.**